# How to better the way I produce phase portraits for saddle fixed points?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I often have to draw phase portraits. Here's an example for the 2D case:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\tikzset{tangent/.style = {
            in angle={(180+#1)},
            Hobby finish,
            designated Hobby path=next,
            out angle={(#1)}
        }}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (fpcrit) at (0, 0);

            \coordinate (lam0v0) at (1, -4);
            \coordinate (lam0v1) at (-1, 4);

            \coordinate (lam1v0) at (1, 1);
            \coordinate(lam1v1) at (-1, -1);

            \coordinate (l0sp) at (1, -3.5);
            \coordinate (l0ep) at (1, 0.8);
            \coordinate (l0csp) at (0.3, -0.5);
            \coordinate (l0cep) at (0, -0.2);

            %========================================
            \draw[thick, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{>}}},
            postaction={decorate}] (lam0v0) to (fpcrit);

            \draw[thick, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{>}}},
            postaction={decorate}] (lam0v1) to (fpcrit);

            \draw[thick, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{>}}},
            postaction={decorate}] (fpcrit) to (lam1v1);

            \draw[decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{>}}}, postaction={decorate}] (l0sp) .. controls (l0csp) and (l0cep).. (l0ep);
            %========================================


            \draw[thick, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{>}}},
            postaction={decorate}] (fpcrit) to (lam1v0);

            \draw[thick, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{>}}},
            postaction={decorate}] (fpcrit) to (lam1v1);

            \node [scale=1.5]at (fpcrit) {\pgfuseplotmark{o}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Drawing the eigenvectors is easy, and I don't think I can further improve how I do that.

I'd like to draw your attention to how I produced the curved line though. Basically, it was trial and error to determine the starting, end and control points (`..sp`, `..ep`, `..cp..` respectively). The control points were chosen so that the curve is tangent to the drawn eigenvectors. Trial and error is time consuming.

I have one idea for how I can improve things: create "standard" phase portraits (where eigenvectors are along x and y axis) which I can then rotate and "squish" as necessary to produce "specific" phase portaits, since basically phase portraits are all "rotations + squishes" of "standard" phase portraits? I illustrate with Paint:

[image]

What would be a nice way to implement this?

Or, is there an even smarter way that I have simply not thought of? Maybe its time for me to move onto using more Lua or Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use a coordinate transformation for the entire `tikzpicture` environment. This will preserve the aspect ratio of any text or arrow decorations; it only affects the path drawing commands.

Having everything packaged in a single command is just for the example; of course in your real use case you'll be placing different things on each phase portrait.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newcommand{\skewedphase}[1][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
    \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0) (0,-1) -- (0,1);
    \draw[domain=0.1:1] plot (\x,0.1/\x);
    \draw (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0.5,0);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,0.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\skewedphase
\skewedphase[x={(1cm,0cm)},y={(0cm,1cm)}] % same as the default
\skewedphase[x={(0.710cm,0.410cm)},y={(0.410cm,0.710cm)}]
\skewedphase[x={(0.710cm,-0.410cm)},y={(-0.410cm,0.710cm)}]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: This might be a very stupid question, but where do the 0.710 numbers come from? I understand that the 0.410 numbers were just something that you picked after to demonstrate skews.

Comment: The two dimensions for `x` are specifying the unit x-vector (Cartesian coordinates), likewise for the two dimensions for `y`. They can be set in terms of any units TeX understands, but not `%` out of the box, unfortunately. For reference (and maybe it helps you understand), the TikZ default settings would be `[x={(1cm,0cm)},y={(0cm,1cm)}]`.

Comment: Also, would this wouldn't leave a node drawn at the centre unskewed, right?

Comment: @user89 that's what I tried to explain (in my second sentence) wouldn't be affected. I added some more things to the example to show this.